# Spel Expression Parser not able to recognise and read the formula in application.properties in SpringBoot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parsing, spring-el

I have a formula stored in my application.properties as follows:-

```
formula.expression=T(java.lang.Math).max((1.0 / T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS.between(T(java.time.LocalDate).now(), loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate()) + 1)), T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS.between(loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate(), T(java.time.LocalDate).now())).
```

T is a special operator  used for referencing types and invoking static methods.
Now i am trying to update my urgencyFactor score by parsing the the formula stored in my application.properties,then evaluating it and then storing the result in my database.
My formula works properly if i store it in my service class and then evaluate it . But then if i store it in application.properties i get this error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error evaluating expression: T(java.lang.Math).max((1.0 / T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS.between(T(java.time.LocalDate).now(), loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate()) + 1)), T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS.between(loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate(), T(java.time.LocalDate).now()))
    at com.realtimeDecision.realtimeDecision.Jobs.LoanPriorityScoreJob.convertExpression(LoanPriorityScoreJob.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.realtimeDecision.realtimeDecision.Jobs.LoanPriorityScoreJob.updateLoanPriorityScoreJob1(LoanPriorityScoreJob.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'comma(,)'
```

I have tried using scriptEngineManagaer, MveL to parse and evaluate it nothing works.

Here is my code:-
Job class:-

```
public ResponseEntity<?> updateLoanPriorityScore() throws LoanNotFoundException, IncorrectStatusException {
        long loanId = 0;
        List<Loan> allLoans = loanRepo.findAll();
        for (Loan loan : allLoans) {
            loanId++;
            Loan loan1 = new Loan();
            Date date = new Date();
            LoanPriorityScore loanPriorityScore = loanPriorityScoreRepo.findByLoanId(loanId);
            if (loanPriorityScore != null) {
                if (loan.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("assigned") || loan.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("unassigned")) {
                    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
                    LocalDate dueDate = loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate();
                    String urgencyFactorExpression = formulaConfiguration.getUrgencyFactor();
                    Double urgencyFactor = convertExpression(urgencyFactorExpression,loan);
                    System.out.println("loannnnn "+loan);
//                    String urgencyFactorExpression = formulaConfiguration.getUrgencyFactor();
//                    String urgencyFactorString = convertExpression(urgencyFactorExpression,loan);
//                    double urgencyFactor = evaluateExpression(currentDate,dueDate,urgencyFactorString);
                    System.out.println("urgency factor expression inside updateLoanPs "+urgencyFactorExpression);


//                    double urgencyFactor = Math.max((1.0 / (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currentDate, dueDate) + urgencyFactorDivisor)), ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dueDate, currentDate) + urgencyFactorOffset);
                    double loanPriorityScore1 = urgencyFactor;
                    loanPriorityScore.setPriorityScore(loanPriorityScore1);
                    loanPriorityScore.setUpdatedDate(date);
                    loanPriorityScore.setCreatedDate(date);
                    loanPriorityScoreRepo.save(loanPriorityScore);
                } else {
                    loanPriorityScore.setUpdatedDate(date);
                    loanPriorityScore.setCreatedDate(date);
                    loanPriorityScore.setPriorityScore(0.0);
                    loanPriorityScoreRepo.save(loanPriorityScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
    }
```

Here it works properly if i store it in database as :`-double urgencyFactor = Math.max((1.0 / (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currentDate, dueDate) + urgencyFactorDivisor)), ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dueDate, currentDate) + urgencyFactorOffset);`
But as soon as  I use convertExpression it dosent work here is the code for it:-

```
private double convertExpression(String expression,Loan loan) {
    System.out.println("dueDate"+loan.getDueDate());
    try {
        System.out.println("exp"+expression);
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        evaluationContext.setVariable("loan", loan);
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);
        System.out.println(exp+"jhasbufwqfi");
        Double evaluatedValue = exp.getValue(evaluationContext, Double.class);
        System.out.println("evaluated"+evaluatedValue);
        return evaluatedValue;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error evaluating expression: " + expression, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does formula.expression in application.properties really have a period/fullstop at the end? How is formula.expression injected? '@Value("${formula.expression}")

Comment: What does that period do in the end of your expression? The `loan` SpEL variable must be used as `#loan`. You can just have a unit test in Java to be sure that your expression is correct. For now it looks like there is some syntax typo, e.g. extra parenthesis. To be honest I wouldn't such a complex logic with SpEL: you always can have a static method with that one and call it from the expression. This has nothing to do with `scriptEngineManagaer`: SpEL is not a scripting language.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I was trying to find the difference between due date and current date if the current date passes due date the formula becomes cur_date-due_date

Comment: Well, I didn't ask about the meaning of your expression: I just pointed to syntax errors. The syntax and logic must be covered by the unit test in your project. Probably after doing that you'd have the question like this in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in formula.expression - extra close parenthesis here loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate()**)** + 1, try:

```
formula.expression=T(java.lang.Math).max((1.0 / T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS.between(T(java.time.LocalDate).now(), loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate() + 1)), T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).DAYS.between(loan.getDueDate().toLocalDate(), T(java.time.LocalDate).now()))
```